# Rotating gameobject with Joystick

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Trying to rotate my gameObject with Joystick, I did previously a script that gameobject was facing mouseInput and I want exactly the same but while using joystick?

```
 public class FaceMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
void Update()
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))

    {

        Rotation();

    }

}

void Rotation()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(
        mousePosition.x - transform.position.x,
        mousePosition.y - transform.position.y);

    transform.up = direction;
}
}
```

I was searching and I found this script, but gameobject doesn't rotate like clock, it rotate my gameobject on other axis, any idea how to make my object to copy JOYTICK movement just like in first script ?

```
public class PlayerMovements : MonoBehaviour
{
public FixedJoystick joystick;
public float speed = 10f;
public float roatateSpeed = 40f;

public GameObject rb;


private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<GameObject>();


}


private void Update()
{
    float horizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
    float vertical = joystick.Vertical;

    Vector3 frameMovement = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);




    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(frameMovement);
    transform.rotation = rotation;
}
}
```

Comment: what on earth is `FixedJoystick`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
float AxisFactor = 90;
transform.localEulerAngles += new Vector3(vertical, horizontal, 0)*AxisFactor*Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help.

Not sure maybe I didn't explained good.

I like the player to be rotate clockvise or anticlockvise with joystick.